# Powershell copy file to all users LOCALAPPDATA creating paths

Tags: windows, powershell, copy

I have butchered a few scripts and I am having trouble getting this one to work.

Using an application to deploy software, I can run a custom script post-deployment.

This application is copying the script and a bunch of files to a location before launching them.
The folder path could be random so I want to use the script location.

- \Path

  - Script
  - File 1
  - File 2

I want to copy File 2 to the Users %LOCALAPPDATA% paths. The directory structure does not exist yet in the Users AppData folder.
I need to create the folder structure during or before the copy.

C:\users*\AppData\Local\NewApplication\Folder\

```
#Declare location of the XML file using spli-path. Copy XML file to all user %LOCALAPPDATA% paths and create folder structure
$scriptPath = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$Source = Join-Path $scriptPath 'Script.ps1'
$Destination = 'C:\users\*\AppData\Local\NewApplication\Folder\'
Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force -Recurse}
Exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This should get it done for you.

```
$scriptPath = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent 
$Source = Join-Path $scriptPath 'File2.xml' 
$Destination = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\New Application\Folder" 
if (!([system.io.directory]::Exists($Destination))){ 
    [system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory($Destination) 
} 
# This will only copy the XML file
Get-ChildItem $scriptPath | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Destination -Force -Recurse} 
# This will copy everything in the same directory as the script
#Get-ChildItem $scriptPath | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Destination $Destination -Force -Recurse} 
#Exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So I totally missed the line to set source as the location of File 2.
Had a go at using the code you posted. Received an error.

`$scriptPath = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$Source = Join-Path $scriptPath 'File2.xml'
$Destination = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\New Application\Folder"
if (!([system.io.directory]::Exists($Destination))){
   [system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory($Destination)
}
Get-ChildItem $scriptPath | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Destination $Destination -Force -Recurse}
#Exit $LASTEXITCODE`

Comment: Error: `Join-Path : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '$scriptPath = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent $Source = Join-Path $scriptPath 'File2.xml' $Destination = "$env' does not exist. At line:2 char:11 + $Source = Join-Path $scriptPath 'File2.xml' + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: ($scriptPath = S...ination = "$env:String) [Join-Path], DriveNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand`

Comment: Based on your code, you dont need to tell it where the Source is. The $ScriptPath will copy all files in that folder location with it and everything below.
I assume you only wanted to copy the XML and not the script itself, if so then I have edited my answer for you.